# How to get a currently dragged element?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I want to get the *currently* dragged element and swap it with `e.target`, when the `dragover` event is raised. Here is the pseudo-code of how I think this task should be done:

```
function swapWhenDraggedOver(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   swap(currentlyDraggedElement, e.target);
}

// swaps two dom objects
function swap(obj1, obj2){ ... }
```

So, how can an element, that is dragged at the moment, can be accessed?

Comment: How are you calling `swapWhenDraggedOver`?

Comment: It's just an event handler of the `dragover` event

Comment: "`[...] and swap it with e.target, when the dragover event is raised.`" - Do you want to swap the elements while dragging over (to indicate reordering intention) or when dropping the elements?

Comment: I want to swap the elements as soon as dragover event is triggered, to indicate reordering intention, as you said.